# TypeError: The superclass is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get my program to use `this.state`, however I got this error. Anyone know how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use as `Component` instead of `Component()`.

Try as:

```
export default class Tables extends React.Component {
   // definition
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: To add up to this response, it seems you used the syntax that is used to create a function, but inheritance works differently. There are some examples that explain inheritance a lot better. https://javascript.info/class-inheritance

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I can't believe I didn't notice.